# How do I implement a function prop for the React-Selectize library in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I'm currently trying to implement the MultiSelect feature of the [React-Selectize](https://github.com/furqanZafar/react-selectize#readme) library, specifically using **Typescript**.

The `MultiSelectProps` are defined as such:

```
export interface MultiSelectProps extends SimpleSelectProps {
  anchor?: OptionValue;
  createFromSearch?(items: OptionValue[], search: string): OptionValue;
  createFromSearch?(options: OptionValue[], values: OptionValue[], search: string): OptionValue;
  defaultValues?: OptionValue[];
  ...
```

In my code, I am attempting to use a MultiSelect element with the `createFromScratch` prop implemented so that users can add a new item to the list by typing in some text and then clicking enter. I'm unsure of how to program this in a way that the compiler will accept, as with the following code I receive the subsequent error:

```
                    <MultiSelect
                      placeholder="Select fruits"
                      options={['apple', 'mango', 'orange', 'banana'].map(
                        (fruit) => ({ label: fruit, value: fruit }),
                      )}
                      createFromSearch={(items: OptionValue[], search: string): OptionValue => {
                        return { label: search.trim(), value: search.trim() };
                      }}
                    />
```

`Error: Type: (items: OptionValue[], search: string) => OptionValue' is not assignable to type '{ (items: OptionValue[], search: string): OptionValue; ...`

I have not been able to find any resources on how to account for syntax with Typescript, and [the guide I found here](http://furqanzafar.github.io/react-selectize/#/) hasn't done me any good so far. Additional attempts by myself to try and weasel the syntax into working haven't worked either, only producing some variation of the above error message.

EDIT: Here's the full error message in VS.

[image]

EDIT 2: The only way I am currently able to get the syntax to stop throwing an error is to encapsulate the function (incorrectly) somewhere else and pass it in:

```
                    <MultiSelect
                      placeholder="Select fruits"
                      options={['apple', 'mango', 'orange', 'banana'].map(
                        (fruit) => ({ label: fruit, value: fruit }),
                      )}
                      createFromSearch={this.createFromSearch}
                    />
```

Where `this.createFromSearch` is defined as:

```
const createFromSearch = {
  (_items: OptionValue[], search: string): OptionValue => {
    return { value: search.trim(), label: search.trim() };
  };
};
```

Which doesn't work, since you can't just surround an empty function with an object in Typescript. Naming the function brings the error back in the MultiSelect.

Comment: That looks right to me. What's the rest of the error message?

Comment: @loremdipso I've attached a screenshot of the whole message for you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a limitation of typescript. From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675822/typescript-how-to-define-overloaded-function-type):

> When you provide multiple call signatures in the interface anything you try to assign to that interface must match all of the call signatures.

So, you'll want to write a separate interface, like so:

```
export interface MultiSelectProps {
  createFromSearch?: ICreateFromSearch;
}

type ICreateFromSearch = (items: boolean, search: string) => boolean | ((options: boolean, values: boolean, search: string) => boolean);
```